# "cannot open source file"- headers included, Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c, visual-studio-2015, artoolkit

I keep receiving the error "cannot open source file" in Visual Studio 2015 when trying to compile the "simpleLite.c" from AR Toolkit. This occurs despite placing the the full paths to the headers in the project options include setting and also pasting  the headers into the project headers folder.
AR Toolkit is installed as C:\Program Files (x86)\ARToolKit5

The include paths, which are pasted into the project include setting, are:
C:\Program Files (x86)\ARToolKit5\include\AR;
C:\Program Files (x86)\ARToolKit5\include\win32-i386\GL

All include files fail to open:

[image: Include errors]

Is anyone aware of additional needed configuration?

Comment: As we cannot see (a) where your toolkit is installed, (b) how you have specifically configured your include path and whether it was done so correctly, and (c) which specific source files Visual Studio is complaining about, the probability of getting anything besides "make sure stuff is where VS can find it, and you've told VS where it is" seems remote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The include paths, which are pasted into the project include setting, are: C:\Program Files (x86)\ARToolKit5\include\AR; C:\Program Files (x86)\ARToolKit5\include\win32-i386\GL

Seeing that the `#include` directives start with `AR` and `GL`, you probably should not have those subdirectories in your include paths, but just

C:\Program Files (x86)\ARToolKit5\include; C:\Program Files (x86)\ARToolKit5\include\win32-i386